# Can't fix UV glitch

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv

I was sure that this glitch was a toplogy problem, but I deleted the face and re-filled the edges together, but still cannot seem to get rid of this glitch.
[image]
It looks like there is a distinct line in the UV that is messing it up. I tried it with multiple images and it still looks like a glitch...

I've attatched the .blend file:
[image]

Comment: the triangulation of the face causes this, you need to divide it a bit with some vertical and horizontal edges

Comment: Hmm, I tried adding knife cuts/ subdividing the surface but it still glitches. (Can't do loop cuts)

Comment: I can't test with your image as you didn't pack it in your blend file but look, it seems to work: https://zupimages.net/up/21/29/rmln.jpg

Comment: Did you just use knife cuts?

Comment: yes I've used the knife (K to activate, C to cut orthogonally)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The artifact stems from your UV mapping, not the topology. To fix the UV map to be flat, select the face of the screen and go into an orthographic side view.

Then, unwrap by projecting from view.

[image]

Because you're in orthographic view and the face is flat, the resulting UV vertices will be correctly spaced.

Now the distortion is gone, but the scaling is wrong. To fix scaling, go into the UV editor and select the entire island that corresponds to your phone screen and scale it along x & y until proportions are correct.

[image]